# R correlation matrix with spearman

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I would like to create a correlation matrix and and present it in a correlogram I used the code below but discovered that the results are based on Pearson correlation test. I would like to have the same graphic with Spearman rank correlation test. What changes to the following code do i need to make in order for me to use spearman instead of pearson?

```
corrplot(cor(hamth17),
         method = 'number', number.digits = 2, 
         number.cex = .8, tl.col="black", tl.srt=45,
         type = "full") # show full chart
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: [`cor(hamth17, method = "spearman")`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor)

Comment: Thank you! it worked :)